# string indices must be integers in python why?

Tags: python, string, error-handling

I'm trying to create a function that gets a list of strings and returns a new list of only the strings that the first character and the last one equals

`

```
def compareLastAndFirst (list):
    newList=[]
    for i in list:
        st=list[i]
        if (st[0]==st[len(st)-1]):
            newList.append(st)     

    return newList
list=input ("Enter your list")
print (compareLastAndFirst (list))
```

and i get an error "string indices must be integers
p.s I only started to code in python recently

Comment: `for i in list` sets `i` to each character in the string, not the indexes.

Comment: `input()` returns a string, not a list.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in function/type.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets change the name of variable from `list` to `inputString`.

Now when you get the input from user it is a `String` and you need to convert it to list.

When you iterate over a string with `for i in list1`, the value of `i` is set to the character in string one by one. Now, when you do `inputString[i]` you are trying to access a character at particular index but providing 'character` as index value which is not allowed.

You can take user input and convert it to list as below :

```
inputString = raw_input("Enter your list")    # You can simply type in your strings with comma separation (>>string,test,pool)
strList = inputString.split(",")
```

Rest of your code is okay and will work as expected. If you want to optimize a little below is a way :

```
def compareLastAndFirst (strList):
    newList=[]
    for i in strList:   # this gives you the strings in list one-by-one.
        if (i[0]==i[-1]):     #you can access the last index of string by giving index=-1
            newList.append(i)     
    return newList

inputString = raw_input("Enter your list")
strList = inputString.split(",")
print (compareLastAndFirst (strList))
```

You can also try different ways of taking user input and directly converting/mapping them to a list. This might be helpful https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-a-list-as-input-from-user/